# How to copy parent styles in stylus

Tags: properties, copy, parent, extends, stylus

Is there more pretty variant of extending such things:

`.mt1
  ...
  #New_Tunnel
    ...
    .livraison
      ...
      .droite
        ...
        .type_livraison
          @extends .mt1 #New_Tunnel .livraison .droite`

Something like:

`.mt1
  ...
  #New_Tunnel
    ...
    .livraison
      ...
      .droite
        ...
        .type_livraison
          @extends &`

Thus, I just want to copy full list of properties of the parent (I have added this line just because stackoverflow forced me to :|)

Comment: Can you explain why you need it? There is no such possibility yet, but depending on your use case there could be different workarounds.

Comment: My selector have to be heavier than client's selector and I must make the same styles to some elements and very often they have parent-child relationships.

Answer (score 1):

This is *somewhat* possible. Have a look at this code, it does what you want:

```
.mt1
  #New_Tunnel
    .livraison
      .droite
        color: red
        name = selector()
        .type_livraison
          @extends {name}
```

this produces:

```
.mt1 #New_Tunnel .livraison .droite,
.mt1 #New_Tunnel .livraison .droite .type_livraison {
  color: red;
}
```